# Error writing a file in Android 11 passing a variable as file name

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save files created in a specific directory I choose. I have many reason why I am doing this not locally.

My app had as target up to Android 10, but now I am trying to target Android 11 as well and so far everything works, except for one thing, the files are not saved if I pass a string variable as file name instead of a written name in the StringBuilder.

Let me explain you showing the working code and the not working code:

```
////WORKING
public class MyLoggerUtility {
private static String filename = "MyMonitoring_Log";
static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable = false;
static boolean isExternalStorageWriteable = false;
static String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

public static void addRecordToLog(String var0) {
    if ("mounted".equals(state)) {
        isExternalStorageWriteable = true;
        isExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    } else if ("mounted_ro".equals(state)) {
        isExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        isExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        isExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        isExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    }

    File var1 = new File("/sdcard/MYPATH/LOG");
    if ("mounted".equals(state)) {
        if (!var1.exists()) {
            Log.d("Dir created ", "Dir created ");
            var1.mkdirs();
        }

        StringBuilder var6 = new StringBuilder();
        var6.append("/sdcard/MYPATH/LOG/");
        var6.append(filename);
        var6.append(".txt");
        File var2 = new File(var6.toString());

        if (!var2.exists()) {
            try {
                Log.d("File created ", "File created ");
                var2.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException var5) {
                var5.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            FileWriter var3 = new FileWriter(var2, true);
            BufferedWriter var7 = new BufferedWriter(var3);
            StringBuilder var8 = new StringBuilder();
            var8.append(var0);
            var8.append("\r\n");
            var7.write(var8.toString());
            var7.flush();
            var7.close();
        } catch (IOException var4) {
            var4.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

And the not working one:

```
////NOT WORKING
public class MyLoggerUtility {
static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable = false;
static boolean isExternalStorageWriteable = false;
static String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

public static void addRecordToLog(String var0, String fileName) {
    if ("mounted".equals(state)) {
        isExternalStorageWriteable = true;
        isExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    } else if ("mounted_ro".equals(state)) {
        isExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        isExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        isExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        isExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    }

    File var1 = new File("/sdcard/MYPATH/LOG");
    if ("mounted".equals(state)) {
        if (!var1.exists()) {
            Log.d("Dir created ", "Dir created ");
            var1.mkdirs();
        }

        StringBuilder var6 = new StringBuilder();
        var6.append("/sdcard/MYPATH/LOG/");
        var6.append(fileName); ================> USING THIS IT DOES NOT WRITE THE FILE 
        var6.append(".txt");
        File var2 = new File(var6.toString());

        if (!var2.exists()) {
            try {
                Log.d("File created ", "File created ");
                var2.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException var5) {
                var5.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            FileWriter var3 = new FileWriter(var2, true);
            BufferedWriter var7 = new BufferedWriter(var3);
            StringBuilder var8 = new StringBuilder();
            var8.append(var0);
            var8.append("\r\n");
            var7.write(var8.toString());
            var7.flush();
            var7.close();
        } catch (IOException var4) {
            var4.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have no idea why this does not works only in Android 11. I have all the permits, as I said it does work with the first example, the problem happens only when using the second one.

If i run the log to watch errors i get the Exception: Operation not permitted.
But it does not make any sense to me because if i use "123" instead of my variable it does create it.

Thank you in advance for everyone who will have a look.

UPDATE: Solved thanks to the user @blackapps, answer in the comments.

I was using ":" character in the file name, it was working up to Android 10 but in Android 11 it caused the file not being created.

Comment: Did you check the value passed in `fileName`? What is it?

Comment: I get the right name and also the type is java.lang.String, i suppose is right

Comment: I suggest double checking the passed variable value of `fileName` as @LevM. said. Try to print the value in logcat.

Comment: `Log.d("Dir created ", "Dir created ");` You cannot cry that you created a directory there. Only after calling mkdir() and checking the return value. It will return false on Android 11 as you are not allowed to create that directory there. Dont tell it works on an Android 11 device.

Comment: @ZankrutParmar As i said it seems right, this is what i get:
Original name: 2021-03-06__13:18:28 
In class name: 2021-03-06__13:18:28 
Passed to path name: /sdcard/MYPATH/LOG/2021-03-06__13:18:28.brt
I really can't understand what's wrong

Comment: `Log.d("File created ",... Too early too. And does it throw? Doesnt it return a boolean?

Comment: @blackapps Mate i assure you this code is working 100% using a name instead of a variable. The problem is only when passing the variable name where i wrote in the code where the error is.

Comment: You cannot put `:` chars in file name.

Comment: `:"sdcard/MYPATH" ` It is impossible to create your own directory there.

Comment: `Mate i assure you this code is working `  Can be. But it is bad code. And you now know why.

Comment: What are the values of  var6.toString() in both cases?

Comment: Again i do create my directory in Android 11, i don't even watch that log, i see the log in another log file i create in app on my personal phone and not on the emulator. As i said it does work, only does not work with a variable, won't be a log to break this code

Comment: The final var6 is /sdcard/MYPATH/LOG/2021-03-06__13:18:28.brt

Comment: You catch exceptions which is good. But if there is an exception you do not inform the user. Nor do you stop. You just continue as if all went well.

Comment: `The final var6 is ..` You should tell two values. The working one and the not working one.

Comment: I will fox that too. Thank you very much for the advice

Comment: The working one is /sdcard/MYPATH/LOG/MyMonitoring_Log.txt (file correctly created as first part of the code i posted).
The not working one is /sdcard/MYPATH/LOG/2021-03-06__13:18:28.txt (file not created as second part of the code i wrote)

But if instead of the variable fileName i use "123" --> var6.append("123")
var 6 will be /sdcard/MYPATH/LOG/123.txt and the file will be written (file created)

Comment: You should all have told this already when you made your post. That was the point. And i already told you why the second one is not ok.

Comment: Ok i only read this now "You cannot put : chars in file name", I removed the filename and now it is working as it should. Thanks mate. I can't anyway understand why on previous versions of Android it does works, also with special characters. Strange.

Comment: Sir you solved my day, thank you so much. Sorry for making hard to understand what was the problem, i'm kind of newbie posting questions here. Will sure be more carefull next times. Any chances you know why does this works on previous Android versions anyway?

Comment: Dont know. It should never be possible.

Comment: `you solved my day` You mean: `you solved my problem and saved my day` ;-). Nice to hear such!